# Powershell - working in ISE but not CLI (not recognized as a name of a cmdlet)

Tags: powershell

First venture into PS with a 'simple' script to invoke an AWS Lambda Function.

It works perfectly fine if run within the Powershell ISE, but I cannot get to run from windows CLI.

I have PS7 installed and then as per AWS docs I installed this :

> `Install-Module -Name AWS.Tools.Lambda -RequiredVersion 4.1.466`

The command to run in windows CLI is :

```
pwsh.exe -NonInteractive -NoProfile ./test.ps1 -taskname mytaskname
-option RELOAD_TARGET -timeout 30
```

Error:

> The term 'Invoke-LMFunction' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or executable
> | program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
> | again.

Appreciate if someone a bit more experienced might be able to see what I'm missing ?

Code:

```
# Accept command line parameters
[CmdletBinding()]
     Param (
     [Parameter(Position=0,mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="byname")]
     [string]$taskname='defaulttask',
     [Parameter(Position=1,mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="byname")]
     [string]$option='RELOAD_TARGET',
     [Parameter(Position=2,mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="byname")]
     [string]$timeout='30'
     )

# Set debugging
If ($PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.BoundParameters["Debug"].IsPresent) 
{
    $global:dbug = $true
} else {
    $global:dbug = $false
}

If($dbug){Write-Host "Args>>"}
If($dbug){Write-Host "Task: " $taskname}
If($dbug){Write-Host "Option: " $option}
If($dbug){Write-Host "Timeout: " $timeout}

# Set Payload
$InputData = @{
    task_name = $taskname
    task_option = $option
    start_timeout = $timeout
} | ConvertTo-Json
 
Write-Host "payload:" $InputData

$Result = Invoke-LMFunction -FunctionName mylambdafunction -Payload $InputData -Verbose
Write-Host "result:" $Result

$StreamReader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($Result.Payload)
$StreamReader.ReadToEnd()
```

Comment: In a PowerShell console (CLI), what does `Get-Module -Name AWS.Tools.Lambda` report? I am not sure ISE and PowerShell Core are compatible. No further development is being done on ISE. Many people have moved on to Visual Studio Code. https://code.visualstudio.com/download

Comment: ISE uses Powershell 5.1 (Powershell.exe). This is a different branch as Powershell 7 (PS7 is built on top of .net core, Powershell 5 is built on th dotnet framework for Windows).

Comment: Many thanks all, I had not appreciated that I had different versions installed!
I've now installed the module using PS7 and all working well :)